# Custom Emoji Keyboard

Tags: ios, emoji, custom-keyboard

I am getting a problem for uploading png image from my custom keyboard. I'm using `UIDocumentProxyText` for converting image into `NSData` but it give me result in string format.  Is there any solution so I can send image by using `UIDocumentProxyText`.

Comment: Why duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599566/emoji-custom-keyboard-gives-string-value ?

Answer (score 0):

You are only be able to get unattributed string. As per apple

> A custom keyboard replaces the system keyboard for users who want
>   capabilities such as a novel text input method or the ability to enter
>   text in a language not otherwise supported in iOS. The essential
>   function of a custom keyboard is simple: Respond to taps, gestures, or
>   other input events and provide text, in the form of **an unattributed
>   NSString object**, at the text insertion point of the current text input
>   object.